# Compare two sql data using mysqlworkbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have 3 tables on mysqlworkbench, 1 table need to combine with 2 data ch(17million row) and cl(9million row) suppose to be one table, other table name alldoc.(121k)

Basically i need to combine ch and cl as one table, and compare with alldoc data. Technically they are suppose to be same but people made mistake that why i need to compare. 100 column
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxb4Y.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFAto.png)

I plan to write query till i hit to 100 because i have 100 columns in all data. Just rows sizes are different.

Thank you from advance. I know complicated but i really need to compare these two data writing query

Comment: Can you clarify what the actual question is please? Are you saying you want to combine the results from `ch` and `cl`?

Comment: I need to do two things, one is combine two sql data, they call ch and cl. And then when I compare these data with other data call as alldoc. Note cl and ch has same information as alldoc data.